# iPhone app updates stuck with iOS 9

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone, ios

I find that when I click "update all" in my iPhone 4S the downloads seem to start and then when they are completed, it stays stuck once the apps are fully downloaded.

I update through wifi, so it's not due to data restrictions.

The blue circles with the "stop" sign inside stayed like this for more than one hour.
In the end I stopped them all and had to start and launch each update manually, which isn't ideal, and what I always end up doing.

[image]

PS: This is iOS 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in iOS9 that I thought they addressed in 9.1. Are you up to date?

What used to work for me is like you said, tapping the stop button and re-trying the updates individually.

Comment: But the bug is happening on iOS 9.1 in this current situation, my "software is up to date"